# PHP special characters not showing

Tags: php, utf-8, special-characters

Can anyone help with with special characters and php.

The following php:

```
$IHaventReceivedCode = "Je n'ai pas reçu mon code";
```

is showing as:

> Je n'ai pas re�u mon code

I have tried adding to the file at the top:

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

and also to the head tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

However, the character fails to show.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check if your PHP file itself is being stored as UTF-8?

Comment: If you use plain HTML instead, does the problem persist? It might be an encoding of the whole file issue.

Comment: hw - it's a shared server i don't have access to the php.ini file
Kamikaze - yes works fine when normal plain html

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through, this has been asked many times on SO

Comment: in connection.php: mysqli_set_charset($con,“utf8”);
and in sql collation utf=8

Answer (score 5):

Try to convert the document to that encoding. If for example you are using Notepad++ you can do the following:

[image]

Comment: I tried that but it appeared to remove those characters/convert them to without the accents.

I added:
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');

And it then rendered fine.. however not really sure why utf-8 one didnt work

Comment: No, always encode in UTF-8 **without BOM**; otherwise you can't send headers and the like.

Comment: @user2183216 Because your file is apparently saved as ISO 8859-1.

Comment: ah i see, this is now resolved using this - thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If your files are in UTF-8...
You can try  [utf8_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)
`$IHaventReceivedCode = utf8_encode("Je n'ai pas reçu mon code");`

Or decode [utf8_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php)
`$IHaventReceivedCode = utf8_decode("Je n'ai pas reçu mon code");`

I'm pretty sure that one of them should change the output...

Answer (score 1):

Use a text editor that supports different encoding. If you're using Notepad try switching to a more sophisticated text editor.